# Using etag with pagination to serve data conditionally in chunks

Tags: api, caching, pagination

I have several APIs that serve a large number of records to an application. The API responses are generally user-based (same API might serve different responses to different users).

To make it easier for the application side to get and load the data, the application receives the response in chunks. For example, it makes n consecutive requests, like this:

> /api/myapi/1
>   /api/myapi/2
>   ...
>    /api/myapi/n

The application caches the API responses in it's local memory as objects. In each API response, an etag header is sent back to the application, containing the hashed value of the response. In each request made by the application, this etag value is sent along with request parameters. Based on the etag value, the server determines whether the application has an old response in it cache or not.

In the case of the API's that serve data in chunks, the application still only keeps one etag for API. That makes it impossible for the server to check whether the application's cached data are fresh or not.

An illustration:

In the case of the API above, each time the request is made, the server calculates the etag and sends it along with the response. Each time the application receives a response, it updates the value of the etag. In the end (when the nth call is made), the application only has the nth etag stored.

When the application needs these data again, first it makes the request to the server (/api/myapi/1 ), sending the nth etag. Most probably, the response with the first set of data will be different than the nth response, therefore the server asks the application to retake the data. The application retakes the data and updates the etag. This repeats till the nth request.

As you can see, even if the total response (all the sets of data) have not changed, the server will always compare the etag from the response of the previous set with the etag of the current data. This means that the server response will always be 'retake the data', which is wrong.

The alternatives I came up with are:

1. The application stores all etags and sends etag[i] in the request /api/myapi/i
2. Another way would be for the server to store all etags for every user (which I don't find effective). That could cause a problem in the case when the server successfully has sent a response but the application was not able to update that set of data. The server would not know that the application is still using an old response.
3. The third alternative would be for the server to calculate the etag of the whole response, but send the response in n sets. Every time it would send the same etag (that of the whole sets). This means that the server has to do the same job twice, which I still do not like as a solution.

PS: The front-end developer says that it is not possible for him to store more than 1 etag for each request. That makes alternative 1 somewhat complicated (although not impossible).

Is there any other way to treat this scenario? If not, what could be a more efficient solution?